# ¿cómo almacenar distintas fechas acumuladas referentes a una key? Diseño de Base de datos

Tags: mysql, sql

Mi interés es guardar las diferentes visitas a un cliente y poder listar las visitas acumuladas mediante el número de cliente, y que se vaya actualizando/agregando la lista (sé que eso lo haré mediante una función php que modifique la lista) . Me podrían ayudar con un ejemplo sql? Gracias!

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Hola. En este sitio se pide que nos demuestres que intentaste hasta ahora. Ademas, la pregunta debe ser mucho mas clara. A que llamas key? que son fechas acumuladas? podrias poner un ejemplo de eso tambien? gracias!

Comment: gracias. Lo haré y modificaré la consulta.

Comment: Que es exactamente lo que necesitas? Como estructurar la información en la Base de Datos? O como hacer el Query SQL para eso..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Según entiendo te recomiendo estos dos modelos, pueden estar en conjunto también:

A) Una tabla exclusiva para esta función, donde solamente se añaden las fechas de visitas:

```
CREATE TABLE visits (
  id          BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  user_id     BIGINT NOT NULL,
  visited_at  TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(id),
  UNIQUE KEY visits_uidx (user_id, visit_date)
);
```

**Desventaja:** Aumentará muy rápido el volumen de datos y necesitarás un proceso por detrás que analice los datos para temas de BI por ejemplo y vacíe el período de datos que ya no hace falta, por ejemplo; el último mes se mantiene, el resto se respalda y se borra.

B) Solo si quieres consevar la última fecha de visita del usuario, puedes aprovechar la tabla de usuario por ejemplo, y le añades una columna adicional llamada `last_visited_at` por ejemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  id               BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  email            CHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  password_encrypt CHAR(64) NOT NULL,
  last_visited_at  TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(id),
  UNIQUE KEY users_uidx (email)
);
```

Espero que sea útil.

Comment: @DenKi Te añadi la desventaja y como puedes manejarlo.